# Unable to find element with watir (xpath , id , class , parent , etc)

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm testing a web page (www.bookingay.com) and i cant't click on a specific item , even i can't locate it by xpath.
Once on the page, search a destination and select first hotel option, then on the hotel page there is a booking button that i can't locate.
I've tried several locators but with no success:

```
browser.button(class: 'btnJumpToCheckOut').click /.fire_event ('click')
browser.button(xpath: 'what/ever?).click
```

None of these options are working, even i can not locate several parent divs for this button.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is the thing you are expecting to happen just not happening?

Comment: The error is that the element is not found, i ve tried like 5 uppers divs with no lucky, also i ve tried to search for the next element and click on parent , but no  lucky too

Comment: Can you add the specific html you want to interact with? "Button" only works for a button element, so if it is a "Div" element that just looks like a button, your code here won't work.

Comment: The full html is online , the website is bookingay.com , after doing a search click on the first option to book , yo ll be on the hotel page , and on this page is where i have the issue